# IBM Information Server engine start failed because of DSWLMServer is not enabled

Tags: datastage, ibm-information-server

When I executed the cmd:/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSEngine/bin/uv -admin -start,the process of DSWLMServer not started compared with another current server status, and I entered the path: /opt/InformationServer/Server/DSWLM,read the file start.wlm.log:
WLM is not enabled, can not start it.
And when I executed the cmd:/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSEngine/bin/uv -admin -stop,error:

```bash
\[dsadm@DWETL1 DSWLM\]$ /opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/DSEngine/bin/uv -admin -stop
Stopping JobMonApp
ERROR: JobMonApp not successfully shut down with SIGTERM, trying SIGKILL
JobMonApp has been shut down.
resource\_ tracker has been shutdown.
Stopping DSAppWatcher
AppWatcher: ALREADY STOPPED
ResMonApp: STOPPING
ResMonApp: ALREADY STOPPED
ODBQueryApp: STOPPING
ODBQueryApp: ALREADY STOPPED
EngMonApp: STOPPING
EngMonApp: ALREADY STOPPED
java.net. ConnectException：Refused Connection
java.net. ConnectException：Refused Connection
at java.net .PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (Abs tractPlainSocket Impt.- java:369)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocket Impl.connectToAddress (Abs tractPlainSocketImpt-java:230)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (Abs tractPlainSocket Impt-java:212)
at java.net SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
at java.net.Socket, connect (Socket. java:642) at java.net .Socket, connect (Socket. java: 589) at java.net,Socket,\<init\> (Socket. java: 453) at java.net,Socket,\<init\>(Socket, java:233)
at com.ibm.iis.common,wlm.wrapper,StopServer.sendMsg(StopServer-java:213)
at com. ibm, 11s ,common, wlm. wrapper, StopServer, sendShutdownRequest (StopServer. java: 182) at com. ibm. 11s, common.wlm.wrapper, StopServer, main (StopServer. java:81)
DataStage Engine 11.3.0,0 instance "ade" has been brought down.
```

How to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a config file that requires you to set WLM=1 to enable the WLM capability.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.3?topic=management-configuration-options-workload

Comment: Thank you,but I hd applied to reinstall the system and unified the cluster node config,now the problem had been resolved.